# Keeping Values entered on submit

Tags: php

I have the following code in my input fields to keep date showing when the submit button is clicked

```
<?= isset($_POST['first_name']) ? $_POST['first_name'] : '' ?>
```

But how do i code it for a select area??  eg;

```
<option value="<?= isset($_POST['Prof']) ? $_POST['Prof'] : 'Prof' ?>">Prof</option>
<option value="<?= isset($_POST['Dr']) ? $_POST['Dr'] : 'Dr' ?>">Dr</option>
<option value="<?= isset($_POST['Mr']) ? $_POST['Mr'] : 'Mr' ?>">Mr</option>
<option value="<?= isset($_POST['Mrs']) ? $_POST['Mrs'] : 'Mrs' ?>">Mrs</option>
<option value="<?= isset($_POST['Ms']) ? $_POST['Ms'] : 'Ms' ?>">Ms</option>
<option value="<?= isset($_POST['Miss']) ? $_POST['Miss'] : 'Miss' ?>">Miss</option>
```

Comment: Is that code working for you? Have you tried it?

Comment: the code in the options doesn't hold, but it does in the input and textareas

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you mean:

```
<option <?=isset($_POST['Prof']) ? "value='".$_POST['Prof']."' selected" : 'Prof' ?>>Prof</option>
<option <?=isset($_POST['Dr']) ? "value='".$_POST['Dr']."' selected" : 'Dr' ?>>Dr</option>
<option <?=isset($_POST['Mr']) ? "value='".$_POST['Mr']."' selected" : 'Mr' ?>>Mr</option>
<option <?=isset($_POST['Mrs']) ? "value='".$_POST['Mrs']."' selected" : 'Mrs' ?>>Mrs</option>
<option <?=isset($_POST['Ms']) ? "value='".$_POST['Ms']."' selected" : 'Ms' ?>>Ms</option>
<option <?=isset($_POST['Miss']) ? "value='".$_POST['Miss']."' selected" : 'Miss' ?>>Miss</option>
```

You want there to be a `selected` attribute to the one that was chosen, but in doing so you have to 'jig' the code about to get the `value` to display in the `if` statement too.

Answer (score 1):

Put those values in an array and loop through it to append options to your `<select>` element, while adding the correct attribute (`selected`) if the value is equal to that posted:

```
$vals = Array('Prof','Dr','Mr','Mrs','Ms','Miss');
$select = '<select name="title">';
$postedValue = isset($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : '';

foreach($vals as $title){
    $attr = $postedValue == $title ? 'selected' : '';
    $select .= '<option '.$attr.' value="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</option>';
}

$select .= '</select>';
echo $select;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what you are creating at the moment is a select field. See [W3C HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) for field information. Continue with PHP after you know how to HTML proper.